# "A non well formed numeric value encountered" when calling number_format

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create my own number formatter helper in Codeigniter. But when I call my function, it shows an error:

> Severity: Notice
>     Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Here is my helper function:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('test_method'))
{
    function test_method($var = '')
    {
        return number_format( (float) $var, 0, ',', '.');
    }   
}
```

When I execute in view:

```
<?php echo test_method($price) ?>
```

I get the mentioned notice. How to fix it?

Comment: What's inside `$price`?

Comment: value from database

Comment: Like <?php echo test_method(100000) ?>

Comment: Use the code in my answer (updated to throw an exception), and see what the value is. Sure enough, it's not suitable for being number formatted. You may need to prep it before formatting, or make sure that you only save proper values as price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP's [`number_format()`](https://secure.php.net/number_format) accepts a [numeric](http://php.net/is_numeric) input. Make sure `$price` is numeric.

```
if ( ! function_exists('test_method'))
{
    function test_method($var)
    {
        if (is_numeric($var)) {
            return number_format($var);
        }

        // Invalid input, do something about it.
        throw new \Exception("Invalid number to format: $var");
    }   
}
```

And your default value for `$var` is not a very good choice:

```
>>> number_format('')
PHP warning:  number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given on line 1
```

#### Update

The `$price` is already formatted. Obviously, the problem is that comma:

```
>>> number_format("524,800")
PHP error:  A non well formed numeric value encountered on line 1
```

As you're saving prices with separators (seems to be already formatted), first you need to drop them before number formatting them:

```
if ( ! function_exists('test_method'))
{
    function test_method($var)
    {
        // Prep
        $var = str_replace(',', '', $var);

        if (is_numeric($var)) {
            return number_format($var);
        }

        // Invalid input, do something about it.
        throw new \Exception("Invalid number to format: $var");
    }   
}
```

Think twice; it's not a good practice to save prices as formatted strings. Or if that's not your case, then you r data is being formatted somewhere else along the way before it hits your helper. Eaither way, you need to fix it.

Comment: when I call in view, there is  blank result

Comment: That's because I commented out the exception part. Try it now.

Comment: hmm, when I try to call direct 10000, its work, but when I call the value from my database, there is show an error like  Invalid number to format: 524,800 whereas the format data is int in my table